How to Identify and Analyse Steady-State Signal in Python for Asymptote Comparison?
I am looking to determine the 'steady-state' value of a signal from my graph, specifically the value of the 'flat' part of the curve, so I can compare it to a theoretical asymptote. The theoretical asymptote value I have calculated is approximately 948 AU.
How can I use Python to identify where the signal begins to flatten, i.e., the index at which the signal starts to level out? My plan is to take the average of this flattened signal area and compare it to the theoretical value. Yes, I could do this by eye, but I need to automatically generate an upwards of 100 of these comparisons.
Here is the Signal in question-you can see that the steady-state begins around 20/30 dynamics.

I've considered using regression and thresholding based on a low gradient to solve this, but I'm unsure how to implement this approach or if it's the best solution. Any advice or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. I haven't included any code here; the signal curve is read into a np.array named 'sequence'.
